# Disabling material input text selection with Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I want to disable text selection with Angular Directive. So far I found the angular solution like below that does not work for me(the handler `onSelectStart` is never called).
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDateInput]' ,
  host: {
    '[style.-webkit-touch-callout]': '"none"',
    '[style.-webkit-user-select]': '"none"',
    '[style.-khtml-user-select]': '"none"',
    '[style.-moz-user-select]': '"none"',
    '[style.-ms-user-select]': '"none"',
    '[style.user-select]': '"none"',
  }
})
export class CopyProtectionDirective {

  @HostListener('selectstart') onSelectStart() {
    return false;
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
}
```

Then in my material date picker I did this:

```
<mat-card class="mb-3" appearance="outlined">
        <mat-card-content>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" hideRequiredMarker >
                        <mat-label>DOB</mat-label>
                        <input formControlName="dob" #ref matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" appDateInput>
                        <mat-hint>{{DATE_FORMAT}}</mat-hint>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

Is that supposed to work. Am I doing something wrong?